# Why am I getting an infinite loop with my UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, loops

I'm calling a method that selects the first row of the table view when the view loads.  But for some reason, after the `selectFirstRow` is being called, it goes back to `self.couldNotLoadData = NO` and keeps going back and forth.  Any ideas why?  When the initial if/else loop goes to else, that method isn't called so it doesn't keep looping.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.ichronoAppointments.count > 0)
    {
        self.couldNotLoadData = NO;
        [self selectFirstRow];
        return self.ichronoAppointments.count;
    }
    else
    {
        self.couldNotLoadData = YES;
        return 1;
    }
}
-(void)selectFirstRow 
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unconfirmed, but I bet that when you call `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` from `selectFirstRow` it calls `UITableView`'s delegate's `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

You've got infinite recursion going on, basically. `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` calls `selectFirstRow` which calls `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` which calls `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` ad infinitum.

You need to move your `selectFirstRow` call to `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`. `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is no place to be doing anything complex... it's called VERY VERY often.

And while you're at it, move the logic that checks for number of items into selectFirstRow. i.e.

```
if (self.ichronoAppointments.count) {
    //select the first row
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
} else {
    //don't
    NSLog(@"Couldn't select first row. Maybe the data is not yet loaded?");
}
```

It's more DRY/modular/cleaner that way.